# Cache-Control, expires and last-modified headers with Laravel 7 app not responding with the correct Status Code

Tags: laravel, browser-cache, laravel-7

Ok folks, here is my question

My struggle is with `Cache-Control: public, max-age=259200` header that I have set up via middleware.

Here is how I did it:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainPageController@getMain')->middleware(['cache.headers:public;max_age=2592000', 'cacheable:2592000']);
```

The second `middleware('cacheable:2592000')` on the same route caches responses with Php Redis

Now the problem, I can see that the `Cache-Control` in the response header, but what I do not see is `last-modified` and `expires` headers on all of the `text/Html` type responses.

Also, I somehow need to set up the `Last-Modified` header to correspond with the date from the `updated_at` column. I have tried to add it manually to the main view, just to check if it works, but found another problem, when content is cached with `Php Redis`, the header won't show up.

Also, I do see that the content is served from disk cache yet the `Status Code: 200  (from disk cache)` shown as `200` instead of `304`.

My app is built with Laravel 7 on Ubuntu 20.04 / NGINX with the Forge server.

If you need any additional information, please let me know.

Thanks